# Two entities with the same name in differents packages

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with the same name (but in differents packages) in my project, that cause an exception :

```
Use of the same entity name twice: MyEntity 

duplicate import: MyEntity refers to both packageOne.MyEntity and packageTwo.MyEntity (try using auto-import="false")
```

I tried to set the property `auto-import` to `false` in my `persistence.xml`, but it doesn't change anything :

```
<property name="hibernate.auto-import"  value="false"/>
```

Is there another solution than add a name in the Entity annotation

```
@Entity(name="MyEntity_One")
@Entity(name="MyEntity_Two")
```

?

Comment: It's been answered before here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175547/fix-for-hibernate-error-use-of-the-same-entity-name-twice 

and here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969550/avoiding-hibernate-annotation-exception-when-using-two-identically-named-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am sure you are not getting a compile time error, its deployment error that you must be encountering. the problem is when  you package then into an ear/war before deploying, both the class come to the server. Whilst any JPA application the container does not know which class to invoke, thus it throws an exception

Is it not possible for you to extend one class and carry your operations or you can create an instance of one class in another and add a one-to-one mapping between  them.

Answer (score 4):

This implies you have two tables with the same name in your database, which is highly unlikely.

You'll need to use the Entity.name value, or if you're using JPA you can also use the javax.persistence.Table annotation.